# Perform different actions on selected page elements using different buttons within one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some time ago I asked how to [select multiple page elements and perform an action on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557364/rails-select-multiple-page-elements-and-perform-action-on-them).

I implemented it and it works great. Now I face another problem: **how to make multiple actions for those elements?**

My view looks now that way:

```
<%= form_for :album_slides_multi, method: :delete, id: 'multi-select' do |f| %>
<%= f.submit "Delete selected" %>
...
<% @slides.each do |slide| %>
<tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "ids[]", slide.id, false, class: "multi-delete" %></td>
```

So I have checkboxes and the submit button named 'Delete selected'.
I wish to have another button next to it - 'Move to another album'.

My controller will use `:update` method rather than `:delete` so I assume `form_for ... method: :delete` is not what I can use here.

Comment: I just saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437779/rails-using-checkboxes-to-select-multiple-objects-and-having-a-choice-of-actio?rq=1) in a related Q&A's. In that case I would have to route all my submit buttons to one action on the controller and then decide what method should be run. Is there a better way ? I wish to have it via different routes that will directly point to the correct action.

Comment: Can you make a different form for each action?

Comment: noep as I need to use same checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the easiest way to change the form action depending on the button clicked (or pressed with enter) would be something like this :

```
<form id="form" action="form_1" method="post">
<button data-action="form_2">button1</button>
<button data-action="form_3">button2</button>
<button data-action="form_4">button3</button>
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
$('button').click(function(e) {
    $('#form').attr('action',$(this).attr('data-action'));
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently have a form button that is posting to the `destroy` action.  You are submitting the form data (`params` containing, among other things, the ids of the models that are checked) to the `destroy` action, which does whatever you want with the data collected and submitted through the form.  What you are asking will require another button (or some way of submitting the form) that points to another action (in your case, it looks like you want to use `update`), but you cannot do this directly because the form decides what action to use, not the button.  So what should you do?

**What you really want:**

The answer is to have the form post to an action of your choice (probably a custom one you create because in your case it won't make sense to call it `destroy` or `update`).

**How to do it:**

To keep things simple, simply change your form to use the `update` action rather than the `destroy` action (because it makes more sense)

```
<%= form_for :album_slides_multi, method: :update, id: 'multi-select' do |f| %>
```

Leave your submit/delete button alone:

```
<%= f.submit "Delete selected" %>
```

Add a new tag for your 'move to another album' feature's button:

```
<%= f.submit "Move selected" %>
```

The above tags give you html that looks like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete selected" name="commit" />
<input type="submit" value="Move selected" name="commit" />
```

Then, in your controller, make your update action read something like this:

```
def update
  if params[:commit] == "Delete selected"
    # your current delete logic
  elsif params[:commit] == "Move selected"
    # your desired move logic
end
```

**More info:**

When you click your `Move selected` button your `update` action will fire and you will make it to the section where `params[:commit] == "Move selected"` because the value of the button was "Move selected" and that value was submitted along with the rest of the params under the name "commit".

If it makes more sense, feel free to create a new action named something more appropriate than `update`.  I won't detail how to do that here as there are plenty of resources explaining how to do that, but using the update action above to accomplish what you want should teach you what you are trying to learn.

This is called a multibutton form and is covered in [Rails Cast #38](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form), but that episode is from 2007 and the exact syntax may be dated in places.

Comment: This is exactly the method described at the link I mentioned above. I'm wondering about some other way. Maybe to use 2 forms with one submit for every, a hidden inputs there and JS to modify those imputs whenever tick-box changed. That way it would be possible to use 2 routes / controller's actions.

Comment: I have looked over your link, again, and it really doesn't seem like it's the same method to me.  Beyond that, while it may be technically possible to somehow (probably by adding many forms (like a form for every single button) or something weird) do it the way you want, it seems like you're heading in a direction that is going to have to pushing against Rails rather than using it in a way to help you.  You have a form > the form will submit to a single action (keep your view simple/dumb) > handle the logic in the action - depending on what button was pressed, do I want to do X or Y ?

Comment: The method is the same as it route to one controller's action for every submit button and there decision is made. One other problem with one route is that it have to handle all parameters for every action. So if I have some additional form field (like destination for the move aciton) than I have to add it to that route even if it's useless and not provided by others.

Comment: >So if I have some additional form field (like destination for the move action) than I have to add it to that route even if it's useless and not provided by others.  
What do you mean by 'add it to that route' ?  The controller action you're dealing with won't mind if there are parameters that go unused for the specific task that's being handled (as long as they're there when it does need them).

Comment: true, it's possible to do that but routes can have different URIs not without a reason. As I want to route to different routes and with different attributes than I wish to use different URIs as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two forms and you want the checkbox actions in the first to be mirrored in the second, you can do this:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KhyGu/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo_form input:checkbox').change(function(){
       $('#bar_' + this.id.replace('foo_', '')).prop('checked', this.checked); 
    });
});
```

Comment: note: sometimes [Ecnalyr's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141574/perform-different-actions-on-selected-page-elements-using-different-buttons-with#answer-23178838) can be a better way. Both are some kind of workarounds for HTML `form/submit` limitations. More about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198407/copy-checkboxes-marks-to-another-form)