# copy checkboxes marks to another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have 2 forms:

**foo:**

```
<form id="foo_form" method="post" action="foo">
  <input class="foo checkbox" id="foo_select_1" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <input class="foo checkbox" id="foo_select_2" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
  <input class="foo checkbox" id="foo_select_3" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="action 1" />
</form>
```

**bar:**

```
<form id="bar_form" method="post" action="bar">
  <input class="bar checkbox" id="bar_select_1" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <input class="bar checkbox" id="bar_select_2" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
  <input class="bar checkbox" id="bar_select_3" name="ids[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
  ...
  # some other input fileds here
  <input type="submit" value="action 2" />
</form>
```

I need JS (jQuery) that for every change of checkbox at `foo` will change corresponding checkbox at `bar`.

The main goal for that is to have 2 different actions for the same checkboxes. I want to hide those at `bar` with CSS and leave only submit button visible. All is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141574/perform-different-actions-on-selected-page-elements-using-different-buttons-with)

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Comment: In that case all I know is that it should be something around `$('.foo checkbox').change(function() { ... })`. I don't know set or unset the value. MrCode's answer looks very promising.

Comment: I wish it would be possible for HTML to have `method` and `action` for `submit` rather than for `form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KhyGu/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo_form input:checkbox').change(function(){
       $('#bar_' + this.id.replace('foo_', '')).prop('checked', this.checked); 
    });
});
```

Comment: @pawel7318 posted the answer there. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very strange thing to have to do. Do you just need to get a copy of the current values from the `#bar_form` form when a box is checked? If so, I would look into using the data `$('#foo_form').serializeArray()` gives you after a change event on it.

```
$('#foo_form').on('change', function () {
  var $form = $(this);
  console.table($form.serializeArray());
});
```